# Extracting data from Wikipedia to a txt file using Python

Tags: python, list, file, web-scraping, io

I have implemented the following code to extract data from a Wikipedia page

```
import bs4
import sys
import requests

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture' )
res.raise_for_status()
wiki = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
for i in wiki.select('p'):
    print(i.getText())
```

This code extracts all the data from the page as I wanted. However I want to store this in a text file using Python but I am unable to. 
The text file should have the name "Agriculture" (better if it is extracted from the url itself so that it can be use over multiple wiki pages).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
wiki_page = 'Agriculture'
res = requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{wiki_page}' )
res.raise_for_status()
wiki = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

# open a file named as your wiki page in write mode
with open(wiki_page+".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for i in wiki.select('p'):
        # write each paragraph to the file
        f.write(i.getText())
```

Comment: Hi. Tried. It gives the following error. 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u016b' in position 74: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi. As much as this works, but why a " .txt " file is not made?

Comment: @Sca updated, now `Agriculture.txt` will be created in your working directory

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Heres a reference.
[Reading and writing files in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
import bs4
import sys
import requests

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture')
res.raise_for_status()
wiki = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

filename = wiki.title.text.split(' - Wikipedia')[0]
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    for i in wiki.select('p'):
        f.write(i.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is compatible with all python versions:

```
import bs4
import sys
import requests
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture"
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
wiki = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
file_to_write = open(url.split('/')[-1]+".txt", "a")  # append mode
for i in wiki.select('p'):
    text_to_write = i.getText().encode('utf-8') 
    print(text_to_write)
    file_to_write.write(text_to_write)

file_to_write.close()
```